# Windows SIM can't create a catalog file from a wim

Tags: windows-10, unattended, wim, answerfile

I'm currently trying to use Windows SIM to create a Windows 10 autounattend.xml file for a custom installation. I have a standard, generic, enterprise edition of Windows 10, which is my source for the wim file.
I can't get Windows SIM to create the catalog. The error I get is just "failed to complete".
I've rummaged around online and the only suggestion I can get is that SIM needs to be a 32-bit installation to generate catalogs for 32-bit or 64-bit Windows images, and a 64-bit installation of WIM can only generate catalogs for 64-bit Windows.
I'm running a 32-bit system, and I'm trying to get a catalog for a 64-bit image, so there's shouldn't be a conflict here.
Does anyone know how to get around this issue, or solve it? I can't even start creating an answer file until I manage to successfully generate a catalog for a WIM file.

Thanks.

Comment: It may seem backwards, but SeanD is correct. 32-Bit Windows SIM can creat 32 and 64-Bit CLG files, but 64-Bit only creates 64-Bit CLG, as shown in at the link below. [Windows System Image Manager Supported Platforms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-supported-platforms)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need a 64 bit "technician's machine" to work with 64 or 32 bit OS's. I don't think you can work with a 64 bit version on a 32 bit technician's machine. When you point SIM to a valid ISO file, it takes a while to create that catalog file, but it's impossible to proceed without it.

Comment: Any sources for this?